# Initializing template pointer function causes differing levels of indirection error

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, template-specialization

I have a general template function pointer taking argument of type `V` and returning type `U` (two templates). I am trying to initialize it using a function taking argument of type `V` and returning `int` (one template) but I get a "different levels of indirection" error (by the MSVC compiler).

Here's the code:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
class A {
public:
    typedef U(*functype)(V);
    const static functype f; //takes type V to U
};

template<typename V>
int myfunction(V x) {
    return static_cast<int>(x+1); //takes type V to int
}

template<typename V>
const typename A<int,V>::functype A<int, V>::f=&myfunction<V>; //causes error

int main() {
    auto t= A<int,long>::f(1); //this should return 2.
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what goes wrong in the assignment. `typename A<int,V>::functype` should be `int(*)(V)` with template `V`, and I am assigning another function with template `V`. I still get an error even if I write `=&myfunction` instead in the code above.

Comment: If you want to partially specialize a class you need to do it for the whole class, you can't do it for a single member of the class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't writing ```A<int,V>::``` partially specializing it for both members (in the line causing the error)?

Comment: It doesn't matter if all the members are specialized, you still need to specialize the class itself. You can't do it for members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So how do you specialize the class? If I write ```template<typename V>
A<int, V> B;``` and then use ```B<V>``` in place of ```A<int,V>``` I now get internal compiler errors

Comment: `template<typename V> A<int, V> B;` is not a specialisation. `template<typename V> A<int, V> { ... content ... };` is.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yeah I tried that but it still doesn't work (with empty content)

Comment: Your specialisation has empty content, hence, no `f`. You refer to its `f` as if it's there, but it's not. If you want it to have `f`, you need to put `f` in there.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sorry I'm confused. I don't want ```A<int,V>``` to do anything more than ```A<U,V>``` when ```U=int```. Do I have to copy-paste the existing code in the specialization content?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Or should I not try to specialize the template in that case? And have it completely general (even though it will only really be used with U=int in main)?

Comment: "Do I have to copy-paste the existing code in the specialization content?" Copying will work, but it is not the only way. You can inherit from the main class instead.

Comment: "Or should I not try to specialize the template in that case?" Remove `U` and use `int` directly. Or add `U` to `myfunction`. Or specialise for `U=int`. There is a lot of possibilities.